# How to add a route rule dynamically?

Tags: controller, laravel-4

I have a website with a backend that downloads "zip files" from another website. Every zip contains a php file that is a Controller (extends from `BaseController`).  Once the controller is downloaded, it is moved internally to `/app/controllers` folder to be ready for requests. However, this will not work because it is not registered at `/app/routes.php`.

My question is, how can I registered this controller dynamically at routes.php without add it explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a really nice answer, I guess...

1. Create a new directory `/app/forms` for new controllers. So, every download package will move it into it, with the following structure:

   ```
   /app/forms/
       form1/
           Form1Controller.php
           routes.php
       form2/
           Form2Controller.php
           routes.php
   ```
2. Add `/app/forms/` to **autoload classmap** at `composer.json`.
3. Edit `/app/routes.php` in order to make dynamic includes:

   ```
   foreach (File::directories(app_path('forms')) as $formDir)
       File::requireOnce("{$formDir}/routes.php");
   ```
4. Run `composer dump-autoload` to update classmap

Now I do not need to light a candle and do a pray to the god of laravel.